# When I have the backing data already, how do I get PaperClip to generate a file URL without instantiating the entire object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've run into a situation where, for performance reasons, I want / need to use a view to load data instead of fetching a root object, then related objects in an N+1 query.  Instead of repeating that query everywhere, I want to code it in a view (using scenic-views) so I can re-use the basic logic -- instead of copying the entire query then modifying raw SQL, I can use the view and then standard active record query methods.

Unfortunately, part of the data I need to serialize in my response is generated by PaperClip, and I'm not sure how to work around this.

My user model has a photo, stored via PaperClip.  When serializing my data, I can serialize this as easily as `user.photo? ? user.photo.url : nil`.  Unfortunately, since I'm not instantiating a user class, while I have all the *components* of the resulting url (my view fetches the entire user table, and adds extra data) I'm not sure how I can put them together to generate the *actual* URL.  I don't want to call the database again to instantiate a user object, but I don't think I can instantiate the user object with the existing column data.

I feel like I'm probably missing something insanely obvious in here, some way to instantiate the user object using the fetched column data, just not seeing it.

Comment: what is the current performance impact when you load the user object? Lot of the times we optimize for something that isn't an really an impact

Comment: @emaillenin the problem isn't loading _one_ user object.  A lot of my root performance issues boil down to N+1 queries, where I query one object, then it's relationships trigger a series of additional DB queries.

In this case, I'm using a view to query the Users table + a bunch of relationships, but that means I'm not loading data into a User object anymore.  I've _got_ the user data, just not as a User object.

Answer (score 0):

So it may not be ideal, but I found a way to do this.

In my view object, I mimic the relevant data methods by instantiating a user object:

```
  def photo?
    User.new(user_attributes).photo?
  end

  def photo
    User.new(user_attributes).photo
  end

  def user_attributes
    attributes.slice(* User.column_names)
  end
```

Long term, I think I may want to move some of this logic into a helper in the view layer.  Leaving it in the model object backing a DB View seems... like a bad placement.